# How to pass the closest common ancestor to superclass type parameter in Java

Tags: java, types, tuples

Let's say I have class `TupleN<T...>` which I want to derive from some type `Tuple<T>` like so:

```java
// with Tuple1 that seems okay
class Tuple1<T> implements Tuple<T> { ... }

// but what should I put instead of ***?
class Tuple2<T1, T2> implements Tuple<***> { ... }
```

What I want is a some sort of behaviour that allows me to define methods that accept not any raw typed `Tuple`, but a `Tuple<T>` with some upper bound type restriction (e.g. for heterogeneous container implementation):

```java
void accept(Tuple<Number> tupleOfNumbers) { ... }

...

Tuple<Integer, Float, Double> t = new Tuple3(123, 12.5f, 43.99d);
Tuple<Integer, Float, String> t2 = new Tuple3(123, 12.5f, "43.99");

// ... some Tuple logic here

accept(t); // Okay!
accept(t2); // not okay, common ancestor is not a Number!
```

I know that conversion from `TupleN` to some homogeneous `Tuple<T>` is possible through static generic methods:

```java
class Tuple<T> { ... }

record Tuple2<T1, T2>(T1 val1, T2 val2) {

  // ...

 static <T, T1 extends T, T2 extends T> Tuple<T> toTuple(Tuple2<T1, T2> t) {
   return new Tuple<T>(t.val1, t.val2);
 }
}

// ... somewhere else
var t = Tuple2(123, 123f);
Tuple<Number> l = Tuple2.toTuple(t); // types T, T1 and T2 are inferred properly and that works!
```

That works, but seems completely pointless as I simply can replace `Tuple<T>` with `List.of()`.

So I can't figure out the non-static way of doing this other than adding an explicit third common ancestor type parameter:

```java
record Tuple2<T, T1 extends T, T2 extends T>(T1 val1, T2 val2) implements Tuple<T> {}
```

Maybe I'm missing some good approach? Please tell me if you have had the same issue.

Comment: "but seems completely pointless" Exactly! You just reinvented the list. Is there anything special that you want a `Tuple<T>` to do, that a `List<T>` cannot do?

Comment: I guess there should be `accept(t1);` and `accept(t2);` (instead of `accept(t)`).

Comment: *"I simply can replace Tuple<T> with List.of()"* - right, `List.of()` is an equivalent of your `TupleN`.

Comment: @Sweeper sure! `List` is a collection, that has its own type hierarchy, has methods `add`, `remove` etc. I want to create clear and straightforward API which tell the user that this particular method accepts exactly tuples, not an `ArrayList` or something. That's because I called `static` method approach pointless, as it doesn't include inheritance and `TupleN` is not a subtype of `Tuple`. Example with inheritance on the other hand is a complete opposite of pointlessness.

Comment: The problem of using just Lists here and there is that that kind of API does not restrict misusage, e.g. mutation, and sure that misusage will lead to runtime errors. If that problem is unsolvable than I should either really just use `List` with some comments "please do not use `List` as `List`, otherwise everything breaks" or use raw-typed `Tuple` just as marker-interface, also with comment "but here must be only `Number` tuples, otherwise everything breaks". All I want to know: Is it REALLY unsolvable? =)

Comment: Lists created using `List.of` do not allow `add` and `remove`, and the standard library lives with this just fine. I really don't see a problem here. What *if* I gave your method an `ArrayList`? It wouldn't and shouldn't break, right? That's the whole point of interfaces.

Comment: There is no generic and useful way to solve this problem.  You have listed all the possibilities.  There is no clever solution that you haven't thought of yet.